# Objective C , keeping Data in a UItableView View even after the closing the Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, xcode4.2

I am developing an App using XCode 4.2 and in a section of the Application I need to store NSString format strings in a UITableView and save use it again when the application restarts...

the data is saved in an `NSMutableArray` variable . I found a tutorial that was using an old XCodeversion that had this piece of code :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSArray *archivedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    if (archivedArray == nil) {

        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];                 

    } else {
        data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:archivedArray];
    }
}
```

and this function

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{

    NSString *dataFilePath;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataFilePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test App-Info.plist"];
    return dataFilePath;

}
```

I get the following two problems:

1-data is not saved ... even when I switch views
2- when I stop the application from the device (i.e. I double click on the Main button and remove it from the list of running application) the application crashes :it goes to this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorld18AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and in the line : `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloWorld18AppDelegate class]));` I get a green error `Thread 1 : program received a signal "SIGKILL".`

any Ideas why it is doing that ?

Edited :
if there is any missing information in my description , please let me know

edited :

the data is saved using this function

```
-(void)saveData{
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:[data copy] toFile:[self dataFilePath]];
}
```

Edited :
question : do I maybe need to have a loadData function somewhere ? if yes what needs to be in it ?

Comment: I can't see where your data is being saved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are archiving an array of strings, you do not need to use NSKeyedArchiver; NSArray provides writeToFile and initWithContentsOfFile methods. Try them, as you'll be less confused about what's happening. When you do, *use the results* to see whether they are succeeding (I notice you are failing to capture the BOOL that tells you whether your data is being saved, for example).

You need to run this independently of Xcode because you can't use the technique you describe where you force-quit the app if the app was launched from Xcode - you'll crash if you do that. Instead, you must load onto the simulator or device by running the app, stop the app in Xcode, and then play around with the app on the simulator or device independently. Now, unfortunately, you can no longer see the app in Xcode, so you'll have to insert lots of NSLog statements and study the console later to see what happened.

Comment: I am quite new to the App developpment , do you mind giving me a code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a `loadData` method.  You will probably want to call it in either your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or your view controller's `viewDidLoad`.  It should look something like this:

```
- (void)loadData
{
    data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:self.dataFilePath];
}
```

As matt pointed out, you could instead use `NSArray`'s `writeToFile:atomically` and `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` methods.

Regarding `SIGKILL`: that is normal behavior.  When you "double click on the Main button and remove it from the list of running application", the system sends it SIGKILL.  A SIGKILL signal terminates the receiving process with extreme prejudice.  If you don't want your app to get a SIGKILL, don't "remove it from the list of running application".

Comment: Hello Rob
I tried to put it in the the viewDidLoad function and it works perfectly fine except for the following cases :
when I terminate the application (by double clicing on the Main button and remove it from the list of running application) the data is erased
when switching views the data is erased , even when I call the function loadData
thank you for the SIGKILL information , I will keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score -1):

Try to make the application run in background. Go to the info.plist file in Xcode and add a key Application does not run in background and set it to NO

For the SIGKILL error, it looks like a memory problem. Try to debug the program using NSZombies.

Comment: I changed the value in plist as you instruct me , nothing happened , still he data in the table gets erased even when I switch views ...

And the memory leak problem disappeared ... I cleaned the application and everything is fine ...